# Search by list of keywords

Tags: java, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have a problem with CriteriaBuilder.
There are two classes

```
public class Filter {
    Integer id;
    List<String> keyWords;
}

public class Entity {
    String name;
    String description;
}
```

I want to get filters that matches Entity.
Imagine we have an Entity(name = "abc", description = "test description asd")

And filters:

1. id = 1, keyWords = ["java", "javascript"]
2. id = 2, keyWords = ["test", "java"]

Expected that filter 2 will be returned because description ("test description asd") contains word "test".

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = new EntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Filter> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Filter.class);
        Root<Filter> root = criteriaQuery.from(Filter.class);
        Predicate predicate = cb.like(root.get("keyWords").as(String.class), entity.getDescription());
        CriteriaQuery<Filter> cq = criteriaQuery.select(root).where(predicate);
```

This query returns empty result, but it works if "test description asd" change to "test" or "java"...
It is possible to divide description field by space and add many predicates, but IMO it's wrong way) Description field could contain many-many words

I was trying different approaches, but didn't find solution. Could anybody assist?

Comment: You didn't show the JPA mappings, so how is keyWords mapped in the database?  From "test description asd" working, it seems you have the list concatenated in the DB column. Check the docs on how the LIKE operator works - you need wild cards if you want to find 'test' in any part of the full concatenated list of strings - try "% test %" if you want to match against the full word.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. There is no relationship between keyword -it is just list of words (strings).
I know how 'like' works, but here I need find filters that matches strings. 
I have "test description asd" as input parameter and I need to find all filters if a filter contains "test", "description" or "asd". And it's a problem, because if I had reverse situation (find strings that contain words) it would be easy task...

Comment: You still haven't shown your mapping -We would need this info to make a query that does what you want, or figure out if what you want is at all possible in SQL. If you understand how like works, I don't understand why you'd think "'java' like 'test description asd'" should work (if that is what is happening in the SQL generated. You seem to expect something more along the lines of "'test description asd' like '%java%' - reverse of what you have, with % concatenated to each side of the keyWord string. path = cb.concat('%', cb.concat(keywordPath,'%') )

Comment: There is no relationship between theses two classes...
keyWord - it's String list, could contain many values.
'test description asd' like '%java%' - cb.like() function takes only Expressions in left part, I can't pass 'test description asd' there...

Comment: You are making this too complicated. I understand what a List of strings are and how it works, but there are many ways to map it. Ie element collection, or even serialized into a single column - show the mapping! So far 'entity' is just a place holder for a string parameter, and has nothing to do with the query - Have you tried a parameter expression instead of a string? ParameterExpression<String> parameterExpression = cb.parameter(String.class);cb.like(parameterExpression, cb.concat('%', cb.concat(keywordPath,'%') ));.. query.setParameter(parameterExpression, entity.getDescription());

Comment: Otherwise, if you want something to do with the Entity class/table, you need to detail more - if this Entity instance is coming from the DB somehow, you can do it in the database with a single query instead of fetching the entity then fetching all Filters separately.